# Generate form from database in MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to generate form from my database.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FieldsMaster](
    [FieldId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FieldControlName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [FieldDataType] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [FieldControlType] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [DisplayLabel] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [FieldSize] [int] NULL,
    [FieldRegularExpression] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [FieldOptions] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [OptionalQuery] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [REMessage] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [FieldRequired] [bit] NULL,
    [FRMessage] [varchar](150) NULL  
)
```

Generate some data for the table

```
insert into FieldsMaster (FieldControlName,FieldDataType,FieldControlType,DisplayLabel,FieldSize,FieldRegularExpression,
FieldOptions,OptionalQuery,REMessage,FieldRequired,FRMessage,IsActive)
values
('txtOtherInfo','varchar','TextArea','Other Information',400,NULL,
NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL)

insert into FieldsMaster (FieldControlName,FieldDataType,FieldControlType,DisplayLabel,FieldSize,FieldRegularExpression,
FieldOptions,OptionalQuery,REMessage,FieldRequired,FRMessage,IsActive)
values
('txtTitle','varchar','TextBox','Title',100,NUll,
NULL,NULL,NULL,1,'Please enter title')
```

Now this form with it fields is stored in my sql db. I want to generate a form in mvc. How the model should be formed/ how to generate form in view?
I am really confused here. Your help is really appreciated. Thanks

To have more idea, below form should be displayed based on the fields in FieldsMaster

```
Other Information(as label) : TextArea (With Id as txtOtherInfo)
Title (as Label)            : TextBox (With Id as txtTitle)
```

Comment: use **EITHER** database-first or code-first to generate model .Database-first:[e.g.](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/setting-up-database)
Code-first:[e.g.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx)

Comment: Also your question is a bit unclear as what do you mean by `form`?

Comment: @ShawnYan, with Form I mean a data entry-form for the user. I should have made it clear, I am not using Entity framework. I am using Dapper.Net. Data entry form should be generated based on the fields created in the table

Comment: e.g, There are two fields defined in FieldsMastter
 the view should generate a textArea with id=txtOtherInfo
and a TextBox with id=txtTitle and required field vaidation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add form directly from database, you can do.

First you need to do into model an Enum like these (for email):

```
    public int EmailTemplateId { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }    

public enum Emailtype
{
    Base = 0,
    Recovery = 1,
    NewAccount = 2,
    ChangePassword = 3,
    BlockAccount = 4,
    UnlockAccount = 5,
    ForgetPassword = 6
  }
```

So each one of thee represent a different template, and in your template view you have something like

```
<body>
//some code of your template
{-container-}
</body>
```

As you can see {-container-} is the property you change for each template. so you made new containers that you´be insert into sql like

```
<tr>
 <td>Hi {name}. Your password is {password}</td>
</tr>
```

You don´t need  tag here because you have it into your first template and this code

And in controller:

```
   public void NewAccount(string name, string email,string password, string user)
    {

        var from = model.From;
        var loginUrl = model.LoginUrl;
        const string title = "New Register - Stackoverflow";

           EmailsService sendEmail = new EmailsService
        {
            Subject = title,
            To = email,
            From = from
        };
}

          //There is our first template (Base template)
        var templateBase = Get(Emailtype.Base);
          //This one is template who changes (container)
        var templateText = Get(Emailtype.NewAccount);

     //Here you replace Name property of class for your container code
           var body = templateBase.Name.Replace("{-container-}", templateText.Name);


           sendEmail.EmailBody = body.Replace("{Name}", name)
            .Replace("{Title}", title)
            .Replace("{User}", user)
            .Replace("{Password}", password)
            .Replace("{Link}", loginUrl);
        sendEmail.Send();
    }
```

Finally in your sql you can insert code of your container... it show like that:

```
EmailTemplateId=1
Type= 1 //(Recovery ones)
Name=    <tr> <td>Hi {name}. Your password is {password}</td> </tr>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the comment Gerry. Actually idea behind this dynamic data entry form generation is like, from Admin panel user can add any fields (so can't hard-code it in design time, user can add as many fields at runtime).Further I need to save the data which user will enter in this fields and I need to query these fields. Your idea of template is nice but unfortunately it will not work in my case. Any thoughts...